# "RuntimeError: string modified" when I try gsub! incoming string inside each

Tags: ruby

My method gets strings with some urls. Urls can have ascii only symbols or any another:

```
"тест non-latin url http://url.cоm and test only-latin url https://url.com"
```

I want to parse my incoming strings, and then change all matches in the original string as follows:

```
"тест non-url <b>[NON-LATIN LETTERS: http://url.cоm]</b> and test only-latin url <a href="https://url.com">https://url.com</a>"
```

and pass it to the next method.

I used `each` with `gsub!`:

```
def validate_url(string)
  validate_url = string.gsub(/((http|https):\/\/.*?)(\s|$|\n|\Z|\t|\r|<.)/)

  validate_url.each do |link|
    if link.ascii_only?
      string.gsub!(link, "<a href=\"#{link}\">#{link}</a>")
    else
      string.gsub!(link, "<b>[NON-LATIN LETTERS: #{link}]</b>")
    end
  end
end
```

I see `RuntimeError: string modified` error and don't understand why and how to fix that.

Comment: Do you have frozen string magic comment on top of your file?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, no, I doesn't have this comment =)

Comment: Must be it's enabled for entire ruby vm? Take a look at this, sounds familiar? https://github.com/railslove/rack-tracker/issues/105

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, yes, I tried this, but doesn't help=(

Comment: Interesting, I have never used this form of `gsub`. Why not block form and return modified copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For whatever reason that string refuses to be modified. While we haven't yet figured out why, here's how you can sidestep the issue: don't modify the string in-place, return a new string.

```
def validate_url(string)
  string.gsub(/((http|https):\/\/.*?)(\s|$|\n|\Z|\t|\r|<.)/) do |link|
    if link.ascii_only?
      "<a href=\"#{link}\">#{link}</a>"
    else
      "<b>[NON-LATIN LETTERS: #{link}]</b>"
    end
  end
end
```

Then

```
clean = validate_url(string)
```